# HTML not formatted inside div generating error

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have a cfm (ColdFusion) page where I display a `#userHTML#` variable's content inside my div.

```
<cfoutput>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">
        <div id="myDiv" class="panel-body">                
            #userHTML#
        </div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <!-- Some Code Here -->
    </div>
</cfoutput>
```

Sometimes the `#userHTML#` variable has invalid HTML. It may contain open `<div>` tags that are not closed which makes the rest of the code where I have `<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">` be inside the top div (`id="myDiv"`)

Is there a way to make this work so that it doesn't matter what the `#userHTML#` variable contains, it will always have it's content inside the div `"myDiv"`?

Comment: Where is the data for `userHTML` coming from?

Comment: I use a tinymce text editor where my users can create the data, so it is coming from HTML data stored in the database

Comment: Shouldn't the tinymce editor be enforcing the closing tags for you? Do you need to keep that formatting or can you remove all HTML tags from the content?

Comment: I believe so, but for this case it is not. I was wondering if there is a way for me to handle it in the code

Comment: I don't think you want to try and handle every possible scenario here in your code. That's why I referred you to tinymce. It's designed to do that for you. You can use functions like `EncodeForHTML()` to protect your code from the contents of that variable but then you lose the HTML formatting.

Comment: Looking more deep into this, looks like it is not inserting all the #userHTML# content inside the div. Is there a limit of character inside a div?

Comment: No, there is not a limit inside a DIV but there is a limit on query data coming out of a database. Check your datasource to ensure it matches the datatype of the database.

Comment: You also want to make sure that CLOB is enabled for the datasource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser is designed to parse that HTML natively. If you require XML it will apply XML rules and importing incorrectly formated XML will error. If you use HTML, it will automatically correct the errors to the best of its ability (as is the case with all HTML documents.

To achive this you can do (please see comments in code):

```js
// Create a new HTML Document (DOM)
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument ('', 'html', null);
// Add the body
var body = document.createElementNS('', 'body');
// Place the body into the DOM
doc.documentElement.appendChild(body);
// Get body parsed / corrected
body.innerHTML = "<div>This is a test";

// Now place that content into your existing DOM
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = body.innerHTML;
// Get rid of the extra DOM
doc = null;
```

```html
<div id="test">Test Div</div>
```

If you inspect the output HTML you will see the closing `</div>` has been added automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSOUP` to clean that HTML. 
Get the relevant JAR file from either https://jsoup.org or http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/ and put it in you `lib` folder.

Then use JSOUP like

```
<cfset oJSOUP = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup" )>
<cfset oJSOUPWL = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist" ).init()>
#oJsoup.clean( 
    javaCast( "string", userHTML ), 
    "http://example.com/", 
    oJSOUPWL.relaxed().preserveRelativeLinks( true ) 
)#
```

This removes unwanted HTML like unclosed DIVs.